# How to add React and Webpack to an existing .NET web site project

Tags: asp.net, .net, reactjs, visual-studio, webpack

I am maintaining a moderate size web site and need to add some pages. The current technology is a .NET Framework 4.6.2 Web Site Project. I need to add some functionality and already built this in React and WebPack, in another VS Solution/Project. However, I am having trouble to integrate this in the existing Web Site Project.

Using online info, I created a new VS Core project with React. It has React and WebPack and everything builds just nice. Now how do I add the React and WebPack to the existing project? (NB: I do not need TypeScript)

I guess that first I have to add files like

- appsettings.json
- package.json
- webpack.config.js

Then, in the Core project I see file webpack.config.vendor.js *under* webpack.config.js .

[image: screenshot of config files]

Is that essential? I looked for an option in VS to *add* a new item of type Webpack, but there isn't. Or is that .vendor.js file created by Webpack itself?

The JSON files also have sub-files. Is there a smarter way to get these config files, can these be generated, or do I really have to manually create these?

The next question, if the config files are in place, where do I tell VS to actually run npm or webpack?

Then it is a mystery as to where NPM fits in. In the sample project, there is a NPM directory full of modules, but in VS there is no NPM button, just one for NuGet. How to configure VS for NPM?

I feel that I either am missing crucial info on how to get started with React in a VS project, or perhaps this is all such black magic that you should really just start a new project with all this stuff in place from the beginning. Would be a pity because React and Javascript is just great and not too difficult to get results pretty fast, and my existing web site is not going to get started over in a new project.

Any pointers to info to get started is appreciated

---

Update:

After reading the guide recommended by ChrisB, I realized I am having a problem with 'build'. I already managed to get react and webpack to work, but had to build the js stuff manually.

Now my problem definition is more clear. Getting the problem defined is half the solution.

There are lots of guides for configuring webpack, and this guide is one of the better ones, but integration with VS means that webpack gets called when needed automatically, which is governed by MSBuild, which means hacking the .csproj file. With 'hacking' I mean editing directly, because there are no menu options  in VS to add a build step for npm or webpack. The guide has a link to MSBuild in the last paragraph.

Comment: I am trying to get my head around what you are trying to accomplish here, at the moment you have built a website with .NET framework and you'd like to expand it ? You would like to use React as your front end while the .NET would provide a back end and some business logic ?

Comment: Just make sure you have Node installed and you can manage NPM packages directly from Visual Studio. It can be tedious to get everything rendering properly, there's a decent guide [here](https://codeburst.io/how-to-use-webpack-in-asp-net-core-projects-a-basic-react-template-sample-25a3681a5fc2)

Comment: @ChrisB. Thanks for the link. Turns out that I already did most of the steps in the guide, but this gives more understanding to configure my next project. Also, the guide has a very useful link in the last paragraph, for docs on MSBUILD, which does what I was looking for to get Webpack called when needed instead of having it to run "manually".

Comment: @PierreChevallier Sorry for my complicated post. My site has many regular *.aspx pages, but I am now developing new pages with more javascript and jquery. However, when adding react I soon discovered the need for webpack, and configuration gets more complicated. After reading the link from ChrisB I discovered I got stuck on the 'build' problem, not the webpack config. Yes, if I new that before, I would have asked a more to the point question, or no question at all!